# Completely hide table on SSAS Tabular

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, tabular

I have a requirement that I'm not sure If I should use perspective or roles or a combination of both.

Basically there is a table on my tabular cube that certain users cannot see so I created two perspectives, one with that table and one that hides the table. That is great but nothing stops users from selecting the perspective that has access to the table I want to hide.

So I created a role and on the "dax filter", I added "=FALSE()" (according to this post https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213165.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which prevents values from being displayed but the problem is that the table is available to be selected.

What's the best way to solve this requirement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to hide table name for a specific user in SSAS Tabular.
As you know perspective is not a security solution and The best way is prevent displaying value by creating Roles as u did.

Regards,
Arman